# Is this a algebra map?

Tags: differential-geometry

I want to prove that the pullback of multilinear form defined as [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_(differential_geometry)#Pullback_of_bundles_and_sections), I mean as in Spivak's book Comprehensive introduction to differential geometry volume 1 chapter 4 is an algebra map, this is because I want to express

$$f^*\left(\sum_{j_1,\dots,j_k} a_{j_1\dots j_k}dy^{j_1}\otimes\cdots\otimes dy^{j_k}\right)$$

in terms of $dx^i$, so I think that if we prove that indeed we have an algebra map we get that

$$f^{*}(\mathscr{T}_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes \mathscr{T}_k)=(f^{*}(\mathscr{T}_1)\otimes \ldots \otimes f^{*}(\mathscr{T}_k))$$

Then in our case we get that $\mathscr{T}_i=dx^i$.

> **Attempt**

- For the tensor product we have

$$f^{*}(\mathscr{T_1} \otimes \mathscr{T_2}(w_1,...,w_k))=\mathscr{T_1} \otimes \mathscr{T_2}(f(w_1),...,f(w_k))=\mathscr{T_1}(f(w_1),...,f(w_k)) \otimes \mathscr{T_2}(f(w_1),...,f(w_k))$$

- For the sum we have

$$f^{*}(\mathscr{T_1} + \mathscr{T_2}(w_1,...,w_k))=\mathscr{T_1} + \mathscr{T_2}(f(w_1),...,f(w_k))=\mathscr{T_1}(f(w_1),...,f(w_k))+\mathscr{T_2}(f(w_1),...,f(w_k))$$

I've got that

$$f^*\left(\sum_{j_1,\dots,j_k} a_{j_1\dots j_k}dy^{j_1}\otimes\cdots\otimes dy^{j_k}\right)=\left(\sum_{j_1,\dots,j_k} a_{j_1\dots j_k} \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial (y^{j_1}\circ f)}{\partial x^i}(p)\cdot dx^i(p) \otimes \ldots \otimes \frac{\partial (y^{j_k}\circ f)}{\partial x^i}(p)\cdot dx^i(p) \right)=\left(\sum_{j_1,\dots,j_k} a_{j_1\dots j_k} \prod_{l >t}^{n} \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial (y^{j_l}\circ f)}{\partial x^i}(p) \cdot \frac{\partial (y^{j_t}\circ f)}{\partial x^i}(p) \right) \cdot dx_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes dx_n$$

Am I right?

Can someone help me with this? Please

Comment: If $f \colon M \to N$ is a smooth map, $a \colon N \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function, and $T,S$ are tensors on $N$, then $f^*(a T) = (a \circ f)\,f^*T$ and $f^*(T \otimes S) = f^*T \otimes f^*S$ and $f^*(T+S) = f^*T + f^*S$.

Comment: Can you elaborate more please? Is because You did very quickly your steps :)

Comment: I listed three different properties of pullbacks that might help you calculate pullbacks in the future.  However, I did not prove any of these properties.  It might be a good exercise to try to prove them.

Comment: Right :) but that is my question :) How to prove that calculations

Comment: The first property I have no idea but I will edit my post, just a second :)

Comment: Ready :) I've edited my post

Comment: @JesseMadnick Then Am I right?

Comment: For the first property what can be done?